# loading a CSS stylesheet using STATIC_URL tag

Tags: css, django, url, static, stylesheet

In my website, I have integrated a stylesheet and a javascript file. I loaded it as follows:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/filterlist.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The javascript works, but the stylesheet does not. I also tried it like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="P:/Daten/Projects/Vorbild/templates/static/css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all">
```

when I do this, the stylesheet will load, but when I run the page from a computer which has not connected to this P:, the css file would not load. (The same problem occurs while loading an image too)

At first, I thought it's a problem in my settings file, but if that is the case, why does the js file works / loads ? Following are snippets from my settings file:

```
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = ("P:/Daten/Projects/Vorbild/templates/static/",
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'klasse',
-->not all are postet now
TEMPLATE_DIRS = ('P:/Daten/Projects/Vorbild/templates/html',)
```

Now the complete urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns
from klasse.views import portal, kundendaten, portal2, error

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^portal/$', portal),
    (r'^kundendaten/$', kundendaten),
    (r'^portal2/$', portal2),
    (r'^error/$', error),
)
```

My folders looks like this:

P:\Daten\Projects\Vorbild\templates\html\allhtml

P:\Daten\Projects\Vorbild\templates\static\css\style.css

P:\Daten\Projects\Vorbild\templates\static\js\filterlist.js

What should I change, so that I can run this page on my server with css stylesheet as well?

Comment: try file://p:/ instead of p:/, but this is only for local use...

Comment: what response code are you getting for the CSS file ?

Comment: sry amyth, i do not understand what you mean with your question :(

Answer (score 0):

Why you just don't group html, css, images ... etc. Put the HTML in `static` folder. Put the CSS file in `css` folder. And just use that path for a source in the `HEAD` of the HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

If I understand you correct I think that's it.

Comment: I think the he is having a problem using `{{ STATIC_URL }}` template tag.

Comment: i have tryed your post, Панайот Толев. but it doesent work. and @amyth, the js is useing the same {{ STATIC_URL }} but have no probs with it.